# Is it possible to share view controller between iPhone and iPad storyboards?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, uistoryboard

Is it possible to share view controller between iPhone and iPad storyboards?

For example in classic master-detail application we could use same master table view on ipad and iphone. How can I do this?

upd:

I want completely reuse view controller, for example for master table view we would have table view layout, visual setup, autolayout settings, IBOutlets connections, cells visual setup and outlets connections and so on. I don't want to do this twice because layouts usually are too complex and manual editing is error-prone. Is it possible?

Comment: It's just a name reference, did you try it and see a problem?

Comment: When you have a view controller in your storyboard, the utilities pane shows you the name of the class. If you change that, a different class will be used. So you can have a single class which is referenced from multiple storyboards.

Comment: Thanks. You didn't understand question. I want completely reuse view controller, for example for master table view we would have table view layout, visual setup, autolayout settings, IBOutlets connections, cells visual setup and outlets connections and so on. I don't want to do this twice because layouts usually are too complex. Is it possible?

Comment: So you want a standard XIB for that part and then to effectively import it into your storyboard containing all of your other views?

Comment: Yep, and I haven't seen any solution for this for a while

Comment: I don't think you can import it, you'd need to do that first part in code and then trigger segues / view controller loads from the storyboard.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to create XIB and hook XIB into storyboard somehow?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible to use the same view controller for both iPhone and iPad (storyboards). Just keep in mind the difference (e.g. there is no master-detail feature on iPhone), and make sure to trigger device specific functionality only on that particular device ...